# Delete all entries over 15 minutes old

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table which gets around 10-15k entries per minute.  Each one is marked with the current timestamp upon entry. The table is a `MEMORY` table, since losing data is not a concern.

Every minute, I have a script which runs the following query:

```
DELETE FROM tracker WHERE post_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

This query is taking about 1-2 seconds to run, which isn't bad, but it seems that this type of query (deleting everything older than `X`) should be able to perform much faster when being run against a `MEMORY` table. It also has a corresponding spike to the CPU which sticks out like a sore thumb every minute.

Are there any optimizations I can do to my query to run this query more efficiently?

Comment: Do you have an index on the timestamp column?

Comment: Eventually you can calculate the time in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always, you should view the query plan, and post it here. You do that by issuing `EXPLAIN DELETE FROM tracker WHERE post_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)`

Now, the problem is likely that the DELETE query can't use an index, and have to loop through all of your rows.

Even if you already have an index on post_time , it will likely not be used, as by default indexes on MEMORY tables are hash indexes. 
Hash indexes can only be used for equality checks, and not ranges such as `post_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)`

Create a BTREE index on your post_time column,

```
CREATE INDEX post_time_idx ON tracker (post_time) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Changing the index from HASH (default) to BTREE completely eliminated the problem.  The CPU usage graph barely registers the query now.

Answer (score 1):

Make an index on post_time. If rows that match `post_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)` are a small portion of the whole table this should speed up things a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If your table never has more than 15 minutes worth of data in it, you could use a smaller data type than DATETIME to store your timestamps.  Depending on the granularity you care about, you could potentially use a *very* small datatype... With a **SMALLINT** you can store 'minutes since midnight'.  If you were willing to lose even more granularity, you could use a **TINYINT** for a 15-minute granularity.  Of course this requires slightly more complex logic, to handle cases "just after midnight"...

```
DELETE FROM tracker
WHERE (
    EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE FROM NOW()) > 15
    AND post_time < EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE FROM NOW())
) OR (
    post_time < EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE FROM NOW()) < 15
    AND post_time < EXTRACT(DAY_MINUTE FROM NOW()+60)
)
```

The advantage is that the data you have to read and compare is much smaller, so it can be processed faster.  This would make a bigger difference if you were storing your data on disk where disk I/O is proportionally much more important than your memory bandwidth.

Also, for a table with only 10-15k rows, and a proper index, I doubt this would make any noticeable difference--whether on disk or in memory.

Comment: I doubt that this will have *any* positive effect on performance. Most modern computers are optimized to work with at least 32bit values, using a 8 bit value is like having a 10inch pipe and only flowing a 2.5inch run of water through it. Trying to pack smaller values to fill the bandwidth usually have negative impact on performance.

Comment: @Autumn: This approach is _proven_ to improve performance in many situations--which I outlined in my answer.  It most noticeably helps disk I/O--which has absolutely nothing to do with the bit-ness of your CPU. It can also greatly improve the performance of indexes in certain situations, where indexing fewer values helps performance.

Comment: @Autumn: I should also point out that the types of operations that a database does on these integers rarely has anything to do with integer math, so your entire premise that CPUs are optimized for 32-bit integers, and therefore 32-bit integers will perform better, is completely unfounded.

Comment: @Autumn: Oh, and one other point... DATETIME is not a 32-bit data type, either. so even if your point was valid in general (and it's not), it would still be completely invalid in this specific instance.